# Affiliation numbers in Author's Name - using TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, affiliation

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\newboolean{Journal}
\newboolean{Proceedings}
\newboolean{NewProceedings}%                                     02-14-13

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@twocolumn}}
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\col@number}{\@ne}}
                  {\@maketitle}
                  {\twocolumn[\@maketitle]}}%
      {\newpage
       \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
       \@maketitle}
    \@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \let\thanks\relax
  \let\maketitle\relax\let\@maketitle\relax
  \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}}
%
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \newpage
  \null
% \begin{center}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Journal}}
               {\vspace{0.00in}}
               {\ifthenelse{\boolean{NewProceedings}}%               02-14-13
                 {\vspace{1.40in}}%                                  02-14-13
                 {\vspace{1.40in}}}
    \centering
    {\large\bfseries\@title\par}%
     \vspace{1.0em}%
    {\normalsize\normalfont
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
% \end{center}%
  \par
  \vspace{0.5em}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother

\title{Article Title}

\author{
Author 1
%
% ---- The first of two styles for addresses: using footnotes and \thanks ----
\thanks{
Research Associate, Research Centre, University, GPO Box 000, Perth,
WA 000 (corresponding author). E-mail: xxx@edu.au},
%
% Adding a second author with the same affiliation (still using \thanks):
%  \\
Author 2
\thanks{
Research, Research Centre, University, GPO Box, WA 000.},
%
Author 3
\thanks{Professor, Research Centre, University, GPO Box 000, 6845,;
Department of Maths, University of Technology, PO Box 000.}
%
and
Author 4
\thanks{
Research Fellow, Research Centre, University, GPO Box 0000.}
}

\maketitle


This is for test

\end{document}
```

Above code generates the output as:

[image]

For converting HTML, I am using the following command:

htlatex test "xhtml,fn-in" " -cunihft" " -cvalidate -p"

It is converted properly, but the affiliation IDs doesn't come in author's List. Please suggest what went wrong in my codes:

[image]

Comment: Please do not introduce irrelevant tags!

Comment: @TeXnician Apologies....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add line `\let \footnote \thank` to your redefined `\@maketitle` macro:

```
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \newpage
  \null
% \begin{center}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Journal}}
               {\vspace{0.00in}}
               {\ifthenelse{\boolean{NewProceedings}}%               02-14-13
                 {\vspace{1.40in}}%                                  02-14-13
                 {\vspace{1.40in}}}
    \centering
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\large\bfseries\@title\par}%
     \vspace{1.0em}%
    {\normalsize\normalfont
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
% \end{center}%
  \par
  \vspace{0.5em}}%
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable suggestion....Happy New Year....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Happy New Year for you as well